# Скопировать файл в каталог

Tags: java

Должно быть просто, но не работает.

```
File from = new File("d:/time/from/11.txt");
        
        File to = new File("d:/time/to");
        try {
            Files.copy( from.toPath(), to.toPath());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println( e);
        }
```

Вот такая ошибка

```
java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: d:\time\to
```

Comment: Из текста ошибки уже должно быть все понятно. Ну и во втором параметре стоит не то, что там должно стоять.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался с вашей помощью.
Нужно было дописать

```
File from = new File("d:/time/from/11.txt");
File to = new File("d:/time/to/11.txt");
```